# Get file extension from filename with php

Tags: php

I got the filename and path (gallery/thumbnail) where thumbnail can be png,jpg or mp4. it will always have the name "thumbnail" and i will always know the path.

How to find out what format the file is with php?

Edit.

I do not have the full file name (gallery/thumbnail.png) I only go the path without the extension (gallery/thumbnail.)

```
$fileName = "gallery/thumbnail.png' //file could be this
$fileName = "gallery/thumbnail.jpg"; //or this
$fileName = "gallery/thumbnail."; //but i only know this
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 1):

Read [PATHINFO](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use `pathinfo()`

```
$file = "path/to/file.png";
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [manual - pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Quick solution

```
$file_ext = pathinfo('your_file_name_here', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```